# Define max visible length of select/option element

Tags: html, css, html-select, maxlength

I'd like to create a `<select>` field. By default the length of this field is defined by the longest `<option>`. Is it possible to define the maxlength of visible select options when I need to have whole select field 100% of parent div?

Let me show you this in code:

```
<div class = "my-container">
  <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>xyz1</option>
    <option>really really long long long long long string</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

styles:

```
.my-container{
  width:200px;
}
#myselect{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now I want to have my select field 100% width but! I want to display in this select let's say only 20 words (or some px value) of option value and then "..." example:

```
Verylong
Verylonglonglong... (original value: Verylonglonglong1234567789)
```

I tried to add overflow property to #myselect, but it does not work for me.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thats not a Dup, as there are no accepted or well-formed answers there

Comment: This can be done via text-overflow: ellipsis;. Supported in major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow

Comment: if you want to display width of option & select same use this css may help you #myselect option{  width: 100%;}

Comment: none of this options work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JQuery solution to your problem:

```js
var maxLength = 15;
$('#myselect > option').text(function(i, text) {
    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        return text.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';  
    }
});
```

```css
.my-container{
  width:200px;
}
#myselect{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "my-container">
  <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>xyz1</option>
    <option>really really long long long long long string</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what means `$('#myselect > option')` section?

Comment: It means: select the direct option descendants of #myselect